# Master Page code behind not compiling into assembly

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am completely stumped by this problem. I have an ASP.NET web application that contains some master pages. This morning I added a new master page and wired it up to a ASPX. However, I keep getting a Y.S.O.D with the error:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Blah.UI.Web.WebForms.Master.LoggedIn'.

Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#"
             MasterPageFile="~/WebForms/Master/IFrameContent.Master" 
             AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LoggedIn.master.cs" 
             Inherits="Blah.UI.Web.WebForms.Master.LoggedIn" %>
```

At first I thought I'd just spelled something wrong in the master page directive, but I've checked and double checked and that doesn't seem to be it.

Since it said "could not load type" I used DotPeak to check that the code behind class had actually been compiled into the assembly and it wasn't there. The original master pages are there, but the one I added this morning is not.

So, I figured that I'd just built it wrong somehow (I'd already attempted a full rebuild already... but I might as well try again). Still missing.

I checked the csproj file against the previous version in source control and I can see that the new code is there:

```
<Compile Include="WebForms\Master\LoggedIn.master.cs">
  <DependentUpon>LoggedIn.master</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="WebForms\Master\LoggedIn.master.designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>LoggedIn.master</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

... and later in the same file ...

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="WebForms\Master\LoggedIn.master" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If I look at the properties in Visual Studio the .cs files say:

- **Build Action**: Compile
- **Copy to Output Directory**: Do not copy

which is just like the cs files for the Master pages that do work.

I am now completely stumped. I haven't a clue why this isn't working or if I've missed anything obvious.

**UPDATE**

I've just run a build at the command line using the same MSBUILD script that our CI server uses and the assembly that produces does contain the new Master page code behind class. So there is nothing wrong with the project file it would seem.

I then checked the file dates of the Visual Studio output. The Web Application project's assembly is two days old while the other assemblies are up-to-date... I'm now trying to determine why Visual Studio is not building that particular project properly. Any additional ideas of what to check are gratefully received.

**UPDATE 2**

Visual Studio is creating the file after all... it is just putting it in the wrong directory. It is putting a number of project files in `bin` and some in `bin/x86/Debug` under the web application's project. It is also copying files from what looks like old build directories as the file dates are different for some files.

I can only guess that part of the issue may be related to me splitting up some code to attempt to clean up the code base yesterday. But I don't understand how it is ending up between a mix of output between `bin` and `bin/x86/Debug`

Comment: perhaps VS is unable to copy new assembly to bin folder - check output windows to see if file is getting copied or not. You should also check the date of assembly in obj folders. Another issue can be with solution configuration which skips the web project (output window should tell you what is happening anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that what actually happened (looking through the source control history) is that some projects had the x86 platform available and others did not. Recently they all got an x86 platform to make things consistent. However, the output paths for that platform configuration was not set the same across the board, hence the assemblies ending up in different directories.

When I set the platform back to "Any CPU" it worked fine. I'm going to have to go through all the projects making the output paths consistent so that all the assemblies output to the right location.

Comment: Thanks. Almost every aspect of your scenario fit my problem, except I noticed it when modifying an asmx. It was only when I noticed an aspx failed to compile (or so it seemed), that I widened my search and found this.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>> At first I thought I'd just spelled something wrong in the master page directive, but I've checked and double checked and that doesn't seem to be it.</strike>

Also checked the namespace of the masterpage?

> CodeBehind="LoggedIn.master.cs"

Should it be `CodeBehind="LoggedIn.Master.cs"`, with capital M?

Answer (score 1):

Is there potentially a problem with the namespace of the newly generated master.cs file? If the masterpage is in a solution subfolder then it will automatically include the folder name in the generated namespace definition.

On a sidenote, are there any future glasgow .net events getting put together through SDN?

Comment: The namespace doesn't appear to be the issue. See new updates above.

Comment: BTW, not upcoming .NET based Scottish Developer events in Glasgow at the moment. We are working on some new events from August onwards. But we do have a book club meeting later this month: http://gla-book-club-july2011.eventbrite.com/ Keep an eye out on our website http://scottishdevelopers.com or twitter stream @ScottishDevs for updates :-)